# What does a linear transformation do to a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ 1

Tags: linear-algebra

As in the last question i had, I'm doing some linear algebra. This question has me stumped however. I can't seem to visualize it.

$$
T_{B}: R^2 \to R^2,\qquad
B = 1/2
\left[\begin{array}
{rr}1 & 1 \\  
1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right].
$$

What, geometrically, does the linear transformation $T_{B}$
do to a vector in $R^2$?

Thanks

Comment: Look at your previous question, can you link the two together? Hint: look at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, then $B= \sqrt{2}A$.

Comment: that was my post too. This one is different. I can't visualise it so i figured id ask it too.

Comment: The two questions are obviously related, also it's clear by the notation that you use that the question consists of two parts. Part a was your previous question, this is part b. Clearly the idea is to use part a for part b.

Comment: @Mathematician42: Not quite, the're a sign difference in the upper right corner.

Comment: @HansLundmark: You're right, I completely missed that. One can ignore my comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It projects a point onto the first bisector. Indeed, let $v = (x,y)$ and let $w = T(v)$; $w = \frac12 (x+y,x+y)$.

$$\text{slope}(vw)=\frac{y_w - y_v}{x_w - x_v} = -1$$

So $(vw)$ is perpendicular to the first bisector. So, since $w$ is on the first bisector, $w$ is just the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto the first bisector.